# Can't connect to Website - Connection refused - Nginx - SSL

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I'm working with Docker, Nginx and Django. I would like to secure my application with ssl but it won't work.
I got a valid certificate using certbot

This is my nginx.conf file:

```
upstream app {
    server app:80;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name mydomain.de;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
            allow all;
            root /var/www/certbot;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name mydomain.de;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/mydomain.de/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/mydomain.de/privkey.pem;

        location / {
             proxy_pass https://app;
          #  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          #  proxy_set_header Host $host;
          #  proxy_redirect off;
        }

        location /staticfiles/ {
            alias /app/staticfiles/;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

        location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
            allow all;
            root /var/www/certbot;
        }
    }
}
```

That's my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    image: django
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app/
      - ./app/staticfiles/:/app/staticfiles
    command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --chdir /app/ Webserver.wsgi

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 433:433
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
      - ./app/staticfiles/:/app/staticfiles
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/nginx/ssl
      - ./certbot/data:/var/www/certbot

  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB_PORT: "5432"
      POSTGRES_DB_HOST: "myhost"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "mypw"
      POSTGRES_USER: myname
      POSTGRES_DB: dev_db


volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

If I try to access my Website I just see the browser message "Connection refused"

*I renamed sensitive information like domain name and passwords*

Answer (score 1):

Below I'm providing a working certbot **nginx** configuration example:

```
server {
    # show half the users an optimized site, half the regular site
    listen      80;
    gzip              on;
    gzip_http_version 1.0;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied      any;
    gzip_comp_level   9;
    gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
    gzip_types        text/plain text/xml text/css
                  text/comma-separated-values
                  text/javascript
                  application/x-javascript
                  application/atom+xml;
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # side note: only use TLS since SSLv2 and SSLv3 have had recent vulnerabilities

    access_log /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.de/logs/access_log;
    error_log  /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.de/logs/error_log;
    server_name 3dact.com www.mydomain.de;


    location ~* .+.>(xml|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|swf) {
         access_log off;
         expires 30d;
         break;
    }


    charset utf-8;
    root    /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.de/public/dist;
    index   index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # what to serve if upstream is not available or crashes
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /media/50x.html;

    location ~* .+.>(xml|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|swf) {
         root /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.de/public/dist;
         access_log off;
         expires 30d;
         add_header Pragma public;
         add_header Cache-Control "public";
         break;
    }

    location /dist {
        alias /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.de/public/dist;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/mydomain.de/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/mydomain.de/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}


server {
    if ($host = www.mydomain.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mydomain.de) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.de www.mydomain.de;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

The first **server** block provides the actual locations and certbot configurations, the second one is used by certbot for domain redirections (`www.`). Given you properly map the volumes in **docker-compose.yml**, that should preserve the consistency when you're connecting. Also, make sure ports `80` and `443` get proper exposure outside of the container.

In your **docker-compose.yml**:

```
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 433:433
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
      - ./app/staticfiles/:/app/staticfiles
      - ./certbot/conf:/etc/nginx/ssl # Make sure it maps into /etc/nginx/ssl/live/mydomain.de
      - ./certbot/data:/var/www/certbot
      - ./letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt # This is where options-ssl-nginx.conf and ssl-dhparams.pem are located
```

If you don't have a local `./letsencrypt` dir or the files are located in a different place, please create any dirs, copy the files there and configure the mapping accordingly.